# Detecting Light Intensity Around Characters

Tags: c#, unity, lighting, materials

**Later Edit**

Since there seemed to be a bit of confusion: I am asking this for purely didactic reasons, I'm not searching for the most efficient solution. Reformulated question: I'm working under Unity, and I'd like to know if it would be possible to somehow query the material + shader of each GameObject that has a Mesh Renderer attached to itself, in order to find out how much light has fallen on the 3D model. I'm not very experienced in computer graphics, so this may seem like a stupid question. I'm thinking of something along the line of pixel by pixel comparison of a texture's brightness at any given point in time.

Comment: It depends on how you've implementing lighting in your game. Frequently those calculations are done in the shader, so it'll be difficult to get the result. But it sounds like you're talking like the material somehow does all these calculations without a performance cost. It'll cost just as much to do it outside the context of the model.

Comment: Right, so it's the shader that calculates the thing. Good to know! @costs: maybe my question was ambiguous. I was thinking that instead of taking into consideration the distance between each model and the light source + the light's brightness I could somehow do... pixel by pixel comparisons on the  model's texture (to see how bright they are). Not sure how to put it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm working under Unity, and I'd like to know if it would be possible to somehow query the material + shader of each GameObject that has a Mesh Renderer attached to itself, in order to find out how much light has fallen on the 3D model.

As per Unity's documentation, Unity does not provide such functionality, so it's not possible to achieve what you want.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this documentation? It would probably help later viewers.

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty solution might be to get the position and intensity of nearby light sources and calculate intensity/distance for each, taking the greatest value to be the light level (if you're just after relative levels rather than pure accuracy, such as you might want when making a minecraft clone and deciding whether creatures spawn or not depending on darkness).

Comment: +1. Trying to read back lighting from the graphics system is likely to be fraught with difficulty. It's almost certainly easier and better to just use the logical position of light sources without considering the rendering side at all.

Comment: That's what I said too. I was just asking for didactic reasons, as I was curious if it would be possible to somehow decide how much light falls upon a character based on how bright the rendered materials are.

Comment: If you could mark the answer as correct that'd be great (need the points!) thank you very much :)

Comment: Well damn, I would, but your answer is basically the same as the 2nd and third paragraphs in my question.

Comment: Well there's gratitude. Nice.

Comment: You did not answer my question, it's that simple.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7224/discussion-between-bogdan-marginean-and-nospamthanks)